# Where exactly is "scm/change/title"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm trying to add a scm/change/title menu item for some manipulations of the scm changes, but I cannot find where it goes after being added. I've tested with other menus and the command works. The official doc states that

> The scm/change/title allows you to contribute commands to the title bar of an inline change.

I'm wondering where exactly is this "title bar of an inline change"? Is it hidden somewhere in the window below? I've tried to right click almost everywhere inside the window but still failed to find it ...

[image: where is the title bar of an inline change?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1.18 release [note shows this](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_18#_scm-new-menu-scmchangetitle):

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_18/difftitle.png]

The [doc mentions](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/extensionAPI/api-scm.md#menus):

> There are five Source Control menu ids where you can place menu items, in order to provide the user with a much richer user interface.
>
> The `scm/title` menu is **located to the right of the SCM view title**.
> **The menu items in the navigation group will be inline, while all the others will be within the `…` dropdown**.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!